# If conditions with datetime comparisons

Tags: python

```
def countdown_date(strdate):
    datetimeobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(strdate, "%a, %b %d / %H:%M %p %Y")
    return datetimeobj - datetime.datetime.today()
```

My above functions asks for strdate and it expects data similar to this
`Sun, Dec 12 / 3:00 AM 2022` and the output will be a remaining count of days and hours til that date.

If the remaining days is a negative amount of days I'd like to increase the datetime object by one year and output the count

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the days remaining on your `timedelta` object, you can access the attribute `days`.

```
def countdown_date(strdate):
    datetimeobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(strdate, "%a, %b %d / %H:%M %p %Y")
    delta = datetimeobj - datetime.datetime.today()
    if delta.days < 0:
        ...  # do your thing
    return delta
```

Note here that `delta` is of type [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), and it ONLY holds *days*, *seconds* and *microseconds*. Hence, you can't increment the *year* value on it.

If you insist on incrementing a year on that `timedelta`, you can just add 365 days to it ...

```
def countdown_date(strdate):
    datetimeobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(strdate, "%a, %b %d / %H:%M %p %Y")
    delta = datetimeobj - datetime.datetime.today()
    if delta.days < 0:
        return delta + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
    return delta
```

Comment: Thank you that's helpful. Do you know how I can increment the year?

Comment: @Dan sure. I've edited the answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I never imagined it would be so easy. Thanks!